# How to draw ellipse on an image?

Tags: python, image-processing, ellipse

I am using this function to draw a circle. How can I modify to draw ellipse?

```
def circle_points(resolution, center, radius):
    """
    Generate points which define a circle on an image.Centre refers to the centre of the circle
    """   
    radians = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, resolution)
    c = center[1] + radius*np.cos(radians)#polar co-ordinates
    r = center[0] + radius*np.sin(radians)

    return np.array([c, r]).T
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way is to stretch x-axis and y-axis by a different factor, i.e. to replace `radius` by `x_semiaxis` and `y_semiaxis`, to mean the [semi-axes of the ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-major_and_semi-minor_axes):

```
def ellipse_points(resolution, center, x_semiaxis, y_semiaxis):
    """
    Generate points which define a ellipse on an image.

    Centre refers to the centre of the ellipse.
    """   
    radians = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, resolution)
    x = center[0] + x_semiaxis * np.cos(radians)
    y = center[1] + y_semiaxis * np.sin(radians)
    return np.array([x, y])
```

Note that I use the more traditional formula to have `x` by the cosine, and `y` by the sine, and I avoid including the transposition, just to make plotting easier. You can easily bring it back.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


plt.scatter(*ellipse_points(1000, (10, 20), 200, 100))
plt.scatter((10,), (20,))  # plot the center too
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal')
```

[image: img]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is simple and useful.

Comment: @BurakKahveci https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269681/how-can-i-thank-this-website :-)